# ¿Por qué el primer código funciona y el segundo no?

Tags: java, poo

**Primer código**

```
package ListaVideos;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.JPanel;


public class VIDEO1 extends java.awt.JPanel {

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawLine(100, 100, 500, 500);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame ventana = new JFrame("Introducción a Gráficos");
    VIDEO1 objeto = new VIDEO1();
    ventana.add(objeto);
    ventana.setSize(700, 700);
    ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    ventana.setVisible(true);
    ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

**Segundo código**

```
package ListaVideos;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class VIDEO1 extends java.awt.Component {

    Component c;

    public VIDEO1() {
        this.c = new Component() {};
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        c.paint(g);
        g.drawLine(100, 100, 500, 500);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame ventana = new JFrame("");
        ventana.setSize(700, 700);
        ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ventana.setVisible(true); 
        ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
    }
}
```

*El propósito del programa es dibujar una linea, sin embargo, el segundo código no llega a
cumplir con tal finalidad, sino que, solamente muestra una ventana 'vacía'.
El primer código si llega a mostrar la línea, por favor si alguien puede explicarme
el por qué el segundo código no cumple con la función especificada
NOTA: El segundo código no genera errores en el IDE, solamente no cumple con mostrar la línea*

Comment: en tu segundo código solo estas creando el Jframe por ello solo te muestra la ventana vacia, de querer dibujar la linea debes instanciar un objeto de la clase Video1 y agregarlo al frame creado tal y como lo haces en el codigo1

Comment: Oh, te agradezco. Ahora si funciona.